# How to properly check if a client disconnected from PHP socket?

Tags: php, sockets

Ok, so disconnected clients are returned by socket_select() in PHP. But how do I check if a client disconnected from a PHP socket without producing PHP warnings?

Most threads I have found recommend using socket_read() which would return false if the client disconnected. But that produces the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10053]:
```

I have tried the following code:

```
    // ...

    if (!$connections = $this->_connections) continue;
    if (!socket_select($connections, $null, $null, 0, 100)) continue;
    
    foreach ($connections as $connection) {

      // check for incoming data
      if ($buffer = socket_read($connection, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ)) {

        // ...

      } else if ($buffer === false) {
        if ($i = array_search($connection, $this->_connections)) {
          socket_shutdown($this->_connections[$i]);
          socket_close($this->_connections[$i]);
          unset($this->_connections[$i]);
        }
      }

    // ...
```

I don't feel that suppressing the warning with @ is a trustworthy solution.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php

Edit: It seems that I am receiving some byte data back from socket_read() upon client disconnect. I am using Sec-WebSocket-Key which may be why? string(8) "]!^"

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the end of data, `socket_read()` returns an empty string. So check for that in addition to `FALSE`.

You can simply use `else`, since both `false` and `""` are falsey.

```
    foreach ($connections as connection) {

      // check for incoming data
      if ($buffer = socket_read($connection, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ)) {

        // ...

      } else {
        if ($i = array_search($connection, $this->_connections)) {
          socket_shutdown($this->_connections[$i]);
          socket_close($this->_connections[$i]);
          unset($this->_connections[$i]);
        }
      }
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. socket_read() returns a warning: unable to read from socket. I use false, because I don't want to remove open connections just by an empty string returned. Oh, your $i index are the array keys of socket_select() and they are not the same as in $this->_connections.

Comment: If the socket is in blocking mode, it shouldn't return an empty string when the connection is still open.